# How to loop through CSV files in directory and output them as RDS files

Tags: r, dataset

This is the code I have for now, I keep getting an error that fd is undefined, I tried defining it as 
fd=data.frame() 
but it doesn't work.

**Code:**

```
file<-list.files(pattern=".csv$")  
#file creates a list of csv file names 

for (i in seq_along(filenames))

{
 fd[i]<- read.csv(file[i]) 

#read each csv file
output=c("o1.RDS","o2.RDS","o3.RDS")

#save each csv file as RDS every iteration, 
#with the name as specified in the vector output.

saveRDS(fd[i],file =output[i])     

}
```

Comment: Why index `fd` at all?  You're writing out the file at each iteration, so you hardly need to keep it in memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, although its untested because I don't have a folder of `.csv` files at the moment:

```
library(tidyverse)

files <- list.files("./", pattern = ".csv")

map(files, ~read_csv(.x) %>% 
      write_rds(path = paste0("YOUR/PATH/HERE", basename(.x), ".rds")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining fd as a list?

```
fd <- list()
```

Also in the example above you have a mistake. It should be "filenames" instead of "file".

Here is the result, which worked for me:

```
fd <- list()

file <- list.files(pattern=".csv$")  
#file creates a list of csv file names 

for (i in seq_along(file))

{
        fd[i]<- read.csv(file[i]) 

        #read each csv file
        output = c("o1.RDS","o2.RDS","o3.RDS")

        #save each csv file as RDS every iteration, 
        #with the name as specified in the vector output.

        saveRDS(fd[i], file = output[i])     

}
```